# IDEA 12 error "Cannot reload AVD list: Error parsing /tools/lib/devices.xml"?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I installed new IntelliJ IDEA 12, Community Edition. I used it top open an Android project created in IDEA 11 (the last version before 12 appeared). When I tried to run Android app, I got error:

> Cannot reload AVD list: Error parsing MY_PATH/tools/lib/devices.xml

Did anyone get this error? How to solve it?

This is IDEA 12 for Linux 64bit machines.

**EDIT**

I **am** using SDK Tools r21.

[image]

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yes, I am. Look at the attachment. I installed those back in IDEA 11.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I see there was some fix for IDEA 11. Am I supposed to implement it?

Comment: No, for me it works out of the box in IDEA 12.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Do you have any custom-made AVN config file in linux home directory?

Comment: No. Check that `devices.xml` is valid and that AVD Manager from the SDK distribution can correctly display your devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution for those who (like myself) in IDEA 11.x changed the content of XMl file `Android-SDK/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/tools/lib/devices.xml`.

The solution is to take the file `devices.xml` from **the original SDK folder** and **copy it** to `lib` folder in your Android SDK folder.

No need to touch `devices.xml` in your `.android` directory as IDEA 12 disables it during the installation.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by the original sdk file?

Comment: @TylerPfaff It was a mistake: folder instead of file. I fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Didn't work for me. Downloaded a fresh copy of the SDK, replaced that file and I'm still getting the prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the devices.xml file from "../sdk/tools/lib/devices.xml."

to your local folder:

C:\Users\USERNAME.android\

Solved my problem.

Comment: I was having error message next to it saying ACCESS DENIED. I changed the folder permission from hidden to not hidden and it is working fine now

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reload AVD list: Error parsing MY_PATH/tools/lib/devices.xml  for this error

1. copy device.xml from C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\device.xml
2. replace MY_PATH/tools/lib/devices.xml

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get rid of this error after updating my SDK to 4.3 and sdk platform tools to 18.
Thanks to the link below

[How to have single android SDK and AVD for eclipse and android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881616/how-to-have-single-android-sdk-and-avd-for-eclipse-and-android-studio)