# How to have single android SDK and AVD for eclipse and android studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

I am Eclipse user and developed android application easily on it. But recently when i saw android studio came and offered by android website i thought to give it a shot since it looks very promising. I have downloaded the android studio in my D drive while my previous SDKS and eclipse is installed in C drive C:\NV_ANDROIDPACK\android-sdk-windows\platforms ( I have used Nividea tegra for whole package in past)..

Now the problem is the android studio has downloaded android SDK 4.2.3 by default in D drive while my other previous sdks are in C drive C:\NV_ANDROIDPACK\android-sdk-windows\platforms.

Now i am trying to run android studio with my previous list of sdks and devices. To test this i have changed the project structure from the Android studio as well as modules and directed to the C:\NV_ANDROIDPACK\android-sdk-windows. Now the AVD manager and SDK manager are configured fine and i can see my installed sdk list and can create virtual devices.

But when i run this it gives me error Cannot load AVD list Error parsing C:\NV_ANDROIDPACK\android-sdk-windows\tools\lib\devices.xml . When i opened the xml file for the newer SDK i found some new xml tags has been added so might be this error but not sure how to solve it.

Is there any good way to have both of the IDE with single SDK of android?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was happening due to the older version in the existing sdk of the Andorid SDK tools , which can be update with new revisions. After that the error is gone and now able to run the emulator ...